How much could gravity increase before a military tank is crushed
Suppose we put a military tank (pick any one you want) in an artificial gravity chamber and crank up the Gs. At what point would the entire tank get crushed like a tin can? Let's also assume the atmosphere in the chamber is similar to Earth's.
The closest reference I found was related to tanks and nuclear bomb testing, which showed that a tank could survive an overpressure wave of around 10-20 psi in a repairable state (obviously the crew would be long gone), but 10-20 psi is only an atmosphere or so of additional pressure.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

More than 30g
Consider an F22 raptor which is rated at 9.6g. That is likely with a considerable error margin. It will probably flex the wings but the cockpit and the airframe do not buckle. It is also not "built like a tank".
A car crash at 70mph will generate about 30g and it will crush the Crumple Zones of a car that are designed to absorb the impact without collapsing the passenger cabin or "Safety Cell". Consider also that tanks are rated for crashes as well. The equivalence principle tells us the is no difference between an acceleration due to gravity and one due to change in velocity.
But how much is 20g?
An ejection seat for a jet generates 18g and its is survivable. If your squishy body can take it, so can a tank. Mind you, this much more than most astronauts experience during liftoff, so it is not a comfortable acceleration by any means.
So how much would it take?
This Mythbusters video shows them dropping a car from 4000ft. Running the numbers tells us that the car was going about 250-300km/h with air resistance and other factors. When it lands, it looks pretty crushed to me and I believe this would satisfy OPs standards.
With a starting speed of 250-300kmh, an ending speed of 0, and a deceleration distance of about 2 meters (the height of the car) we end up with 125-175g range. Feel free to check my math.

A human body can survive a constant 20g? It can't. It can survive that much only temporarily, and for 10g the survival time is measured in seconds. While a human might be able to survive a constant load of 2g, maybe even 4g, although there seem to be issues with blood circulation even if the human is prone, but no way it's more. At least 30g listed for a tank is not off by a factor of 100 as you told me, but just a factor of 10.

@Vesper agreed. A constant 20gs will kill you. But will it crush you like a tin can? The last little bit of my answer, I indicate that it is likely in the range of 100g. I almost want to amend it to 100-1000. Steel is strong. We build bridges with it. It would take a lot to crush the steel frame of a tank.

I think this good answer could be improved by altering paragraph 3 to describe that a car crashing and being crushed corresponds to 30 gravities. It's not that crashes are 30g accelerations innately - in fact we deliberately don't build cars like tanks in order to keep the accelerations as low as possible in the event of crashes. Crumple zones, etc. Evidently as low as possible is 30g. (A source or few would be cool too, actually, if you have them on hand.)

"Gravity won't hit you like a wall." and "The equivalence principle tells us the is no difference..." are in contradiction, and I'm pretty sure for this purpose the latter is more accurate. I think the correct conclusion from the comparisons in this answer (which are good!) is "30-175g".

@ShapeOfMatter Correct. I updated the answer to reflect it along with another comment's suggestion regarding crumple zones.

"Gravity won't hit you like a wall." was the correct statement.  "The equivalence principle tells us the is no difference..." is in this case incorrect.  Car crashes are a poor analogy of g forces because forces are concentrated in the terminal impact zone and propagate from failure point to failure point.  It's like the difference between the energy required to break a window by stacking rocks on it vs dropping rocks on it.  Most materials have some level of brittleness which allow them to fail more easily under smaller but faster moving forces.

6-150g by design requirements
I agree with Vesper that the turret ring is most likely going to be the major point of failure, but it will be a lot harder to crush than he supposes.  Other things like the suspension may experience significant flexion before this point making them unable to perform their regular functionality before this point, but the turret ring experiences much more concentrated forces from above weight than the rest of the tank's structure, and when it gives, the turret will drop causing a high speed impact that will crush everything else.
For starters, the military tends to require higher tolerances than civilian engineering calls for.  3-5x tolerances are much more standard for military designs because they are expected to be used in unexpected ways.  At least, this would be true of modern weapon systems designed for use by the US military.  Something as low as 2x might be realistic for weapons designed by other countries or in much older tank designs.
Secondly, turret rings are not just designed to hold the weight of the turret, but it's not allowed to significantly flex under that weight or it will jam and be unable to turn, so the measure of tolerance has to be to a Tangent Modulus which will be much lower than the Ultimate Tensile Strength at which the ring will actually rupture. This means that the turret may jam and be unable to turn at 2-5g but the actual point at which the turret collapses in on itself could easily be 2-10 times this amount of gravity depending on what alloy is used.  I personally suspect it would be closer to the 10x end of the spectrum because a less rigid steel is likely necessary to keep the ring from shattering under impact.
Lastly, modern tanks are designed to tolerances that allow the turret to turn while it drives.  Because driving creates impulses up to 3g, this fixes the minimum possible tolerance to 3x the minimum margin for a total of as low as 6g in older tanks, or as high as 3 times the total margin for more modern tanks that can run-and-gun giving a top design estimate of 150g.

keep in mind a tank bouncing over a hill or drop might easily experience 4 g's of force. so you are going to need a lot more than that if its just sitting static.

@john Yes, that is one of the reasons I said "I personally suspect it would be closer to the 10x end of the spectrum because a less rigid steel is likely necessary to keep the ring from shattering under impact."  My suspicion is that most tanks would require 20-40g to collapse the turret ring, but I kept the range intentionally wide because not all tanks are made to the same standards.  Many early tanks in fact did break down when going over.

thats a good point it may be worth asking the OP to narrow down "tank"

@John perhaps, but if a tank is somewhere that g != 1, then it's probably not any tank that exists today.

Cave-in: 2-4 G (EDIT: 4-10 G)
The tank can be viewed as a mechanism that's designed with a specific "safety margin", or rather a durability margin, which means that the mechanism can survive an extra X% load before it breaks. Given that there is no means to increase gravity in the real world, it was not designed to withstand gravity increase; yet it can be estimated from durability margins used at design time by taking the lowest of them. For "crushed like a tin can", the specific margin should be used, the margin for the tank turret's rotational mechanism. It's designed with expected impulse load of some extra tons when a projectile collides with the turret, and still it's designed with a reasonable durability margin left for industry defects or acceptable errors in production. And the usual value of such margins is 100% to 300%, which are translated into extra 1-3 G, making the final value. The exact value depends on the actual tank, but no tank can withstand 10G, they are not made to suspend several hundred tons of metal on their chassis.
Update: As said in comments, a tank is traversing the uneven terrain, and can also execute small drops to the ground, which puts its hull at a strain of several Gs temporarily. Based on T-90's listed ability to overcome a solid wall 0.85m high, and its clearance of 450+-50mm (model based, adjustable), it experiences a stress of extra 3 Gs from the drop (although only a half of the tank drops at once), so the margins listed above should be raised to include such accelerations at design time.
Splatter: Something too big
Based on the comment "I am seeking the extreme case", the extreme case is when the tank's armor does not have cavities, or any angle of the tank's hull has been bent so that there's almost no space left inside. Therefore, the gravity force should be large enough to bend a tank's armor plating under its own weight. Let's take T-90 as an example: It's listed to have front armor thickness of 500 mm, and it's curved like a C, thus to crush a tank like a tin can requires to bend a steel plate 500mm thick to make contact with its upper part and lower part. But, if it's enough to just put enough force to break the tank's side armor, it's only 90 mm thick, thus the force to make that wall give in is about five times smaller.
Let's estimate that we have a steel sheet 90 mm thick, 1m wide (irrelevant) and about 2m long, with a tensile strength of 1000 N/mm^2 (highest found in a short search), Young's modulus of 500 GPa and density of 8000 kg/m^3 (I don't have data on how dense are actual armors, so I'm using a ballpark estimate), attached to a wall. In order to bend it to at least 45 degrees, which would correspond to "about" a point when the side walls of a tank give in, the material would have elongated by (45 mm \* tan(45 degrees)/(2.0 m) = 0.0225 (and shrunk on the other side by the same relative value), meaning the force applied has to be 0.0225\*500GPa\*0.09 = 1.0125e9 N. This force, however, is to elongate the entire sheet of metal by 2.25%, if we are to bend, the force should be integrated by the sheet's height, as the very center of it is elongated by zero; the load profile by the module looks like a \/ so the force should be divided by 2, making it 5.00625e8 N. The plate's weight under 1G would be 14100 N (1440 kg mass * 1G), thus its weight needs to be increased 5.006e8/1.41e4 ~ 35600 times, meaning that to crush the 90mm armored wall the gravity has to be halfway to the one on a neutron star to actually crush the armor. In fact it makes sense, since a piece of ammo is experiencing about 10000G while being kicked out by the gun and does not crush in the process, but I really feel there was a serious mistake in this napkin calculation.

I like the back-of-the-evenlope calculation, but there is likely a big difference between "tank breaks down" (e.g. turrent won't rotate, gun is toast, tracks/suspensions break) and "tank is crushed like a tin can".

@fgysin I expect that at 4G the turret's suspension structure would cave in, which would probably satisfy OP's requirement. Otherwise, a tank's armor reaches 200mm and would likely not collapse into a flat thing under its own weight until thousands of Gs.

A tank's mechanisms are designed for the peak loads experienced while moving. If it only had a margin of 2x-4x, it would likely break itself going over uneven terrain.

You are off by a factor of 100

@ChristopherJamesHuff true, but there is suspension to hold such temporary loads. With constant loads, suspension would reach its limits and at least cause the load to act on its support directly. Still, a nice addition, since if a suspension is capable to not break if a tank is dropped from a meter above to a concrete floor, it might suffer several Gs temporarily, which would mean that the turret support should also be that much more durable.

@ChristopherJamesHuff as an example, the T-90 is listed to be able to run over a wall of 0.85m high (Russian wiki page), that means, it can drop from that height and remain operational. Since it'll then stop over about 20 cm (half of 406mm clearance), it'll experience about 2G upward acceleration while sustaining the drop, meaning it can temporarily survive 3G. I'm not sure whether this means that a T-90 could indefinitely sustain a 3G gravity, or a 6-12G instead, but it might call for the reassessment.

Reframe it this way:
Do you really think a tank could stack a second tank ontop of it and continue operating normally?
What about two tanks? Three?
It might be able to limp around with one tank's worth of weight magically placed ontop, but all of the margins and tolerances it was designed to handle (as a single tank) are now demolished by extra mass.

@abestrange but how many tanks would you need to stack on top of it before it is crushed like a tin can?
Cars can be stacked 4-6 high before I would consider the bottom one to start being crushed like a tin can.. And tanks are built like a tank.... ;)

Not working is not "entire tank get crushed like a tin can?" Crushed like a tin can means it would like it was put inside of a crusher... And crushed.

OP has also clarified in comments that they are after "the extreme case (crushing the entire tank)," which is significantly beyond just being unable to move.

Okay everyone, have a go at the updated answer. I really feel like I've made some mistakes calculating the forces to bend a steel plate, feel free to find and report them.

Your calculations on your armor are probably not as far off as you think.  If you think about it, thin low-grade steel latticeworks can support several hundred meter tall buildings; so, a solid plate of  armor grade steel that's just a meter tall can hold a LOT more than its own weight... but a tank is not just a plate of steel, it is that plate, plus the interspace angled plates, plus any reactive or ceramic plating, plus the ceiling of the tank, plus the turret, etc... so all of the stuff on top of the plate should be factored in too to arrive at a realistic estimate.

Your question can be translated to: what is the maximum load I can distribute on a tank without crushing its body?
Once we know the maximum load W in Newton, and we know the mass of the tank body M in kg, the maximum gravity it can withstand is determined as $g_{max}=\frac{W}{M}$.
Problem is, tanks are not rated for load bearing and I am afraid the design parameters are not really made available to the general public.
Also comparing the overpressure resistance brings nowhere: a static load like its own weight and an impulsive load like that of an explosion come with different behaviors.

Just start a flame war on War Thunder and someone is bounded to cite the secret documents to shut you down...

@SeanDuggan I am half convinced War Thunder is an intelligence activity desiguised as a game.

@questor It probably wasn't, but after the first couple of incidents I'm convinced that at least two different intelligence agencies amuse themselves by occasionally infiltrating a couple of sock accounts and have them be loudly, beligerently, confidently and blatantly wrong about some minute detail just to see if someone with a security clearance and insufficient common sense takes the bait...

The nuclear test figure for overpressure is probably conservative. An airburst nuclear weapon will do most of its damage with a shockwave that is moving horizontally. This can exert large forces on the sides of buildings that they were not designed to withstand, but may be ineffective against people inside a small tank. If you were in the city, it would not be the overpressure that got you, but the building that it dropped on you.
Tanks would have been tested against the sort of shockwave conditions that might be at the edges of a nuclear strike. I remember an apparatus to simulate nuclear EMPs on tanks and armoured vehicles. That was used to test existing vehicles, and to fix any weak points if they found any. I don't think resistance to shockwaves or to EMPs was a major part of the initial design.
I don't know what G-forces are experienced by Tanks dropped from aircraft but this may be closer to a nuclear shock.
Vesper's answer is probably in the ballpark for a real tank. They are not designed to handle high G forces, so there may be all sorts of parts that break in unexpected ways, rendering it useless. However, if you test your tank at high Gs, and eliminate all the simple modes of failure, then you might go a lot higher.

Hmm, nice mention if paradropped tanks. Yet I'm unaware if they are modded to allow easier drop, for example, if they have lighter turret and cannon and stiffer support. I assume that the supported mass endures about 5G upon contact, and about 2G when retro engines kick in right before landing. The hull of a tank (less turret) would certainly not collapse at this gravity; but there are all sorts of tanks, I was thinking about a more heavy tank like Russian T-90 with its turret being the most susceptible part to increased gravity.

Tanks can go at 50 mph. There was even an experiment one that was clocked at 104 mph in the 1930s. They can leave the ground. They can drop into trenches and climb out. Paradropping is probably stressing the tank in similar ways to driving one fast, but it may be easier to put numbers on it.

Surprisingly little ...
Tanks are rugged. But they also carry heavy armor, which stresses their design almost to the breaking point. I would expect the springs to fail at much less than 2 G. The barrel would also bend soon. The hull itself might last a little longer, but it is optimized to resist the impact of KE and shaped charge penetrators, not gravity.

I would expect the springs to fail at much less than 1 G Huh?  Did you mean to write 10 G?

@JohnGordon, I think I meant 2 G, that is one extra G. But it was two days ago and my estimate has a big error bar.
